# How can I create growl notifcation in angularjs that accepts html as message

Tags: angularjs, dialog, notifications, growl

I want to show growl type notification in my angularJS app (using timer) and use that technique to throw small surveys to user. For that this seems to be a good choice - https://github.com/marcorinck/angular-growl/ - with a catch. This doesn't seem to support HTML TAGS.
Any idea how I can achieve that in simple way ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Latest version of angular-growl does support HTML as part of the message.

[growl-like notifications for angularJS with HTML as part of the message](https://github.com/marcorinck/angular-growl#allow-html-in-messages)

Answer (score 0):

Just a follow up answer, it seems that the original `angular-growl` is outdated.

A fork has been made it seems that is activelly maintained at https://github.com/JanStevens/angular-growl-2.

Per `README.md` file:

> Allows for HTML content inside the alert